# Uploading Processing Sketch with library to github

Tags: git, lgpl, file-structure, distribution

I have a sketch I wrote in the language Processing that I want to put up on GitHub. It uses a library released under LGPL so from what I understand, I'm able to (and should) upload the library alongside it. The library, like most Processing libraries, lives inside `/Processing/libraries` (and from what I understand, it's very difficult to get them running outside the libraries folder), the sketch lives in a folder inside processing (i.e. `/Processing/foo`).

I understand that I could just could `init` git inside the `/Processing` folder and add `/foo` and `/libraries/bar`, though I don't know if that makes life more difficult for the user and it may be difficult if I want to create another repository for another sketch later. Right now I've just got a git repository inside the sketch folder and a readme telling users the library they'll also have to download. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LGPL](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html) says you don't have to put this library with your code and make your code on LGPL. That's the main difference between LGPL and GPL.

You just have to make a way for user to be able to use his own version of this library. So, link it dynamically:

> 0) Convey the Minimal Corresponding Source under the terms of this License, and the Corresponding Application Code in a form suitable
>   for, and under terms that permit, the user to recombine or relink the
>   Application with a modified version of the Linked Version to produce a
>   modified Combined Work, in the manner specified by section 6 of the
>   GNU GPL for conveying Corresponding Source.
>
> 1) Use a suitable shared library mechanism for linking with the Library. A suitable mechanism is one that (a) uses at run time a copy
>   of the Library already present on the user's computer system, and (b)
>   will operate properly with a modified version of the Library that is
>   interface-compatible with the Linked Version.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering this almost a year later.